# What is the difference between bandwidth consumption and speed of IoT protocols?

Tags: mqtt

If IoT protocol has small bandwidth consumption, does that mean its speed is slower?

I heard that MQTT is perfect for when we are restricted in bandwidth, but does that make it slower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I heard that MQTT is perfect for when we are restricted in bandwidth, but does that make it slower?

No, if anything the opposite. The fewer bytes you have to send the shorter the time for the total message to arrive at its destination for a fixed rate of transfer.

MQTT is said to have a low overhead, this means that it sends a very small amount of extra data as well as the actual content of the message you want to send. E.g. when the header can be incredibly small when compared to something like HTTP which has a very verbose text header including things like `User-Agent` and `etag` where as the MQTT packet header just includes the topic, message size and some bit flags for QOS and Retained state, apart from the topic all of this information is encoded in the smallest possible binary form.

The original use case for MQTT was to send data back from an oil pipeline over a satellite network connection, the price was very high to send each byte of information.